# Hidden Field Value to Server Side

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a form submit and I tried to send a selected drop down value to server side through a hidden field but it's not working:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "registerFormId" }))
{
    <select class="form-control" id="districtId"></select>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DistrictId)
}
```

Server Side

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
    {
         // Hidden field value not bind here.
    }
```

Register view model:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    // Some Properties there

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public bool IsGuest { get; set; }
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
    public string ZipPostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you make sure the hidden field is populated when you select a dropdown value? Also post your dropdown in your view please.

Comment: @TechGuy, how do you set drop down selected value to hidden field?

Comment: its because you are not setting anything in your `m.DistrictId` its just a hidden field  . show us how you populate your select element .

Comment: Why do you need a hidden field here? Just bind the drop-down list to your model directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change Id of select to another name, not use same name.

```
<select class="form-control" id="another"></select>
```

Must ensure value of Hidden field have been set when selected before submit.

```
$('#another').on('change', function(){
   $('#DistrictId').val($(this).val());
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You should create dropdownlistfor for that hidden id. You don't need to create hiddenfield.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DistrictId,                
    new List<SelectListItem> { 
    new SelectListItem { Value = "0" , Text = "Option A" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "1" , Text = "Option B" }
    }, new { @class="classname"})
```